# Nikon D300 multiple shots on timer

Tags: self-portrait

I want to take self portrait shots, not exposures, and would like to take a few shots at once a second or so apart.

Comment: Welcome to photo.stackexchange.com! One tip: It always works best, if you question is also clear as such. While we can figure out, what your question is, it is usually best, if you ask.

Answer (score 1):

Disregard my earlier comment. It seems , the easier option is to just use the interval timer shooting option. You can set the interval to 1 second and set the number of shots you would like the camera to take, and the camera would automatically  do exactly what you want.

Check this video    , where she shows how to do this with your camera model
[Interval Timer Shooting on Nikon cameras](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yq8tl1jiKnw)

Comment: @Tetsujin Arent the 3300 and D300 different cameras ?

Comment: Oops, sorry, completely misread it. https://www.manualslib.com/manual/113352/Nikon-D300.html?page=215

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly what I was looking for!!!

Comment: @1wildwes if this answer helped you, please consider upvoting it, or even accepting it by clicking the gray checkmark next to the question. See the help center page, [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)